# set_thread_area in strace

Tags: c, linux, binary, strace

Using strace on a program: strace outputs the same extract output in Debian and CentOS except for set_thread_area. (The program's version is exactly the same on both Linuxes.)

Why are they different ? Is there any way so that the output is the same on both Linuxes ? Can this difference be programmed in C ? Is some package missing in Debian/CentOS ?

```
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb7fb16c0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 3
read(3, "\242\177)", 3)                 = 3
```

```
set_thread_area(0xff9db33c)             = 0
```

**EDIT**
First: CentOS i686
Second: Debian x64 but compiled with -m32

Comment: compare strace versions.

Comment: and provide more details on the 2 systems, like cpu type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about the reason the addresses are different, or why `strace` formats the output differently? If it's the latter, I suspect you're just dealing with two different versions of `strace`, one possibly outdated. However, something also looks odd about this:

```
set_thread_area(0xff9db33c)             = 0
```

The address `0xff9db33c` is definitely not a valid userspace address on i386. Is it possible one of your systems is x86_64? That would also explain the different format, since `set_thread_area` on i386 takes a pointer to a `struct ldt_desc`, while on x86_64 it just takes the actual pointer value to load into the thread register.

Comment: I am asking about the output format. Why does CentOS have urandom and Debian does not ?

Comment: Um, `urandom` is not part of `set_thread_area`. It's a separate thing. At what point in the trace does it appear? I suspect it's setting up a random canary for stack-smashing protection.